# Flex Custom Component Won't Resize

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4

I am trying to create an expanding object with the following event handler

```
public function pickerMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("in mouse move");
    var offsetX:int = e.stageX - touchX;
        trace(offsetX);
    picker.x += offsetX;
        trace(picker.width);
    picker.width -= offsetX;
        trace(picker.width);
    touchX = e.stageX;
}
```

The picker.x += offsetX works just as expected and moves the the x coordinate of the component.

The problem is with the picker.width -= offsetX

The width of the component doesn't change on the screen, but the value of picker.width changes as it is printed out on the console.

Here's some sample output from the trace's:

```
in mouse move
-1
928
929
in mouse move
-1
929
930
in mouse move
-1
930
931
```

Is there something that I don't know about custom components resizing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UIComponent invalidation mechanisms and override `updateDisplayList()` in your custom component to redraw your component with new width.

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer? If you want this to be an answer can you provide a little more background/detail please?